# How the presenter knows about the rows affected by a DAL method

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, mvp

I'm using MVP pattern and exceptions are handled in presenter. User messages like `"Update Successful", "No matching records in DB"` etc will be generated by a separate UserMassage service class available to presenters. (As the messaging is a responsibility of presenter)

So I just want to know how the presenters know whether the DAL method has updated/ deleted rows or failed?

My current approach is shown in this sample DAL method in `DataService` class

```
    public void DeletePoint(string pid)
    {
        string updateStatement = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT PID FROM Attendance WHERE PID = @pid )" + 
                                 "UPDATE Point SET Point.deleted = GETDATE() WHERE PID = @pid";

        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(db.ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(updateStatement, sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@pid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pid;

            sqlConnection.Open();
            var RowsAffected = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (RowsAffected > 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Updated Sucessfully");
            }
            Else
            {
                throw new Exception("Update was not Successful");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Exceptions are certainly the wrong solution. I'm not familiar with MVP but I would expect a message with a `int RowCount` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [@@ROWCOUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) to get the number of affected rows in the database. Then return this in your DAL method to the presenter or service calling the DAL.